# Haskell accessing type-classes parameters problem

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, parameters, typeclass

This is prob an easy question but I just could not find the answer for this:

How can I access the parameters of a custom type?

Lets say my code is like this: (anotherFunc is only there to help me access the parameter)

```
data Shape = (Shape Color [Dimension])

func :: [Shape] -> [Shape]
func (x:xs) = anotherFunc x : func xs

anotherFunc :: [Shape] -> [Shape]
anotherFunc (Shape Color (x:xs)) = <some simple operations>
```

is there something similar to this??

```
func ( (Shape Color (x:xs)):shapes )
```

many thx!!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There is something very similar to that.

```
func ((Shape _ (x:xs)):shapes) = ...
```

However, your `func` just reimplements `map`, so you can use that and continue to use `anotherFunc` (which can be defined locally if you'd prefer):

```
func = map anotherFunc
  where anotherFunc (Shape c ds) = ...
```